Закрывается WebSocket сразу после открытия (Django, Daphne, Redis)
Возникла необходимость внедрения на WSGI Django сайт - чата. Сайт крутился на Apache2 - OS Debian 12. После изучения документации в проект были внедрены redis, сайт хостится на Daphne и в качестве обратного прокси используется Apache2, но после попытки подключиться к сокету он сразу вызывает onclose метод, не понимаю что не так.
• ASGI.py :
import os, sys
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from alyanceproject import routing
from django.urls import path

sys.path.append('/path/to/project')
sys.path.append('/path/to/app')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'path.to.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket" : AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )    
    ),
})

• routing.py:
from django.urls import path , include
from .consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("" , ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
]

• settings.py (кусок с ASGI с CHANNEL):
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'alyanceproject.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    'default':{
        'BACKEND':'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG':{
            'hosts':[
                ('redis-server-name',6379)
            ]
        }
    }
}

• consumers.py :
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.roomGroupName = "group_chat_gfg"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.roomGroupName ,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    async def disconnect(self , close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.roomGroupName , 
            self.channel_layer 
        )

• JS (кусок создающий новый Websocket) :
btnChat.onclick = async function() {

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +'/');

    chatSocket.onopen = function (e) {
        console.log("Соединение успешно установлено!");
    };
    chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
        console.log("Возникла неожиданная ошибка при подключении к сокету!");
    };

• Инфо по портам в системе:
tcp  LISTEN  0  50   i.p.ser.ver:8001 0.0.0.0:* users:(("daphne",pid=192041,fd=9))                                                                                                                                                                                                           
tcp  LISTEN  0  511  i.p.ser.ver:6379 0.0.0.0:* users:(("redis-server",pid=11835,fd=6))                                                                                                                                      
tcp  LISTEN  0  511  *:80  *:*  users:(("apache2",pid=191971,fd=4),("apache2",pid=191969,fd=4),("apache2",pid=191968,fd=4))                                                                                        
tcp  LISTEN  0  511  *:443  *:  * users:(("apache2",pid=191971,fd=6),("apache2",pid=191969,fd=6),("apache2",pid=191968,fd=6))              
tcp  LISTEN  0  511  [::1]:6379  [::]:*  users:(("redis-server",pid=11835,fd=7))  

• APACHE2 (кусок Location):
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName nameServer

        DocumentRoot /path/to/project
        #WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app/wsgi.py
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://i.p.ser.ver:8001/
        </Location>

